# Yii custom session timeout

Tags: php, session, yii

I want to make an interface for admins to change session timeout in my application. Timeout value will be kept in DB.

After changing session timeout value i do:

```
$duration = (int) $this->session_duration;
Yii::app()->session->setTimeout($duration);
Yii::app()->session->setCookieParams(array('lifetime' => $duration));
```

and than echo its values, and everything looks good until I refresh page, and than I get old session timeout value, as well as cookie lifetime.

Also, what's the best place in Yii to put session timeout validation

```
if (time() - Yii::app()->session->get('LAST_ACTIVITY', 0) > Yii::app()->sesstings['session_timeout']) {
    Yii::app()->session->destroy();
}
Yii::app()->session->get('LAST_ACTIVITY') = time();
```

I'm using `CHttpSession` as session component

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

1. Use it in index.php (last line)
2. Use ini_set and set value to "session.cache_expire"

Comment: AFAK all ini_set settings have to be done before session_start() which would be in top of file, not at last line. Also cache_expire is when session cache will expire, not session itself, if you read manual you'll find *_This has nothing to do with lifetime of a session_*